# Show full county name rather than the abbreviated form

Tags: addresses

Appreciate it's a US-bias, but can't find a way to stop the abbreviation of County, eg Essex becomes ESS.

What have I missed?

Comment: Can you provide examples of where you are seeing this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In Administer > Localization > Address Settings, you can change the mailing label format to use `{contact.state_province_name}` instead of `{contact.state_province}`.

[image]

It is not currently ready, but the localization (translation) system of CiviCRM does have support to define better defaults based on the locale. Work is being tracked in: https://lab.civicrm.org/development-team/translations/issues/1